# How to reduce macOS usage of substantial portion of hard disk space for storing iCloud documents

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, icloud, storage

I have a MacBook Pro 256 GB SSD(Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)running Mac OS Big Sur but this issue goes beyond these specs. I have a 2TB iCloud Storage plan, of which 1.54 TB is available. Out of the 245GB total, I have available space of 15.1 GB. Using DaisyDisk, I can see that my biggest space consumer is `~/Library/Mobile Documents` (60GB). I found that this space is used by iCloud to keep iCloud Documents in sync. My usage of iCloud is more like a a backup containing GBs of zip files, which I haven't used in a month or more. So I find it odd that `~/Library/Mobile Documents` will be this big in size. Additionally, I have the `Optimize Mac Storage` done. I have iCloud Drive enabled. Can I adjust the amount of data iCloud caches on my local hard disk? It would be idea to specify like 10GB or so using LRU policy, but if not, what are the options?

[image]

Comment: iCloud is a sync system, primarily, and not cloud storage like Dropbox or OneDrive.  This means it keeps local copies of everything on every device signed in with the same Apple ID. You can't adjust the amount of storage allocated. Do you need access to these zip files from your Mac all the time?

Comment: I don't. My use case is more like Dropbox or OneDrive. I barely need access to those files.

Comment: iCloud isn't any sort of backup, so if that's your goal, find something else.

Comment: If you don't need these files synced for access across all your devices then I recommend not using iCloud.  If you must or want to use iCloud, are these zip files stored in your Desktop & Documents folders?  If so, is that what you have synced to iCloud?